# Ingestion Spec - Flattening An Array of JSON

Tags: druid

I'm setting up a druid ingestion spec and was wondering if there was a way to apply names to the dimension/metric based off value nested in the `JSON`. I currently have a kafka topic which passes system data to consumers, although as you can see in the example `metrics` consists of an array of objects which isn't guaranteed be in the same order. Because of this, I can't target it as such. `($.metrics[0].metric_value)`

```
{
  "metrics": [
      { metric_name: "if_speed", metric_value: 100000 }, 
      { metric_name: "if_prefix_accepted", metric_value: 10 }, 
      { metric_name: "if_prefix_rejected", metric_value: 8 }
  ],
  "dimensions": [
      { dimension_name: "device_name", dimension_value: "foobar" }, 
      { dimension_name: "num_cores", dimension_value: 32 }, 
      { dimension_name: "amt_ram", dimension_value: "128000000000" }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with JQ

http://www.compciv.org/recipes/cli/jq-for-parsing-json/

```
"flattenSpec": {
   "fields": [
       {
              "type": "path",
              "name": "if_speed",
              "expr": "$.dimensions[?(@.dimension_name =~ /if_speed/i)].dimension_value"
       }
    ]
}
```